# importing csv into phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, csv, import, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a dataset that looks like....

```
~01001~^~0100~^~Butter, salted~^~BUTTER,WITH SALT~^~~^~~^~Y~^~~^0^~~^6.38^4.27^8.79^3.87
~01002~^~0100~^~Butter, whipped, with salt~^~BUTTER,WHIPPED,WITH SALT~^~~^~~^~Y~^~~^0^~~^6.38^4.27^8.79^3.87
~01003~^~0100~^~Butter oil, anhydrous~^~BUTTER OIL,ANHYDROUS~^~~^~~^~Y~^~~^0^~~^6.38^4.27^8.79^3.87
~01004~^~0100~^~Cheese, blue~^~CHEESE,BLUE~^~~^~~^~Y~^~~^0^~~^6.38^4.27^8.79^3.87
```

I went to import, uploaded the file....

- selected CSV
- chose the delimeters as:

  - Columns separated with: ~^~
  - Columns enclosed with:  ~
  - Columns escaped with: \n
  - Lines terminated with: Auto

This doesn't seem to work.
What is wrong ?

Comment: Try it with columns separated with ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your "Columns separated with" `^` instead of `~^~`.

Additionally, your columns don't seem to have any escaping in them (you would if you'd have `~` in the data itself), but `\n` can be used at the end of a row. Here it works okay using `\n` for the escape value, but in general it's better to set that to something you know doesn't exist in your data (for instance `or`|`).

You're already enclosing the columns with `~` so you don't need to use the tilde as part of your column separation as well; even though it looks like there are tildes there those are actually part of the markup that encloses the columns, not separates them. It's a subtle distinction, but that worked for me. Hope this makes sense.

This worked for me:

[image]